# Processing Time

Tags: perl, computation-theory

Why does the following script take so many cycles to complete?

The document it is sifting through is 20590 lines long and each line consists of the following, or a variation thereof; 
"10160354001 ALGIERS             ALGERIA     36.70    3.60  290"

I am trying to make a database to match the first number to the last 3.

The actual program is however taking several seconds per line.

Script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

$path = shift(@ARGV);

open COORDS, $path or die "Couldn't open file\n";

my %coords = {};

foreach $line (<COORDS>){
    $stat = substr $line,0,11;
    @coords = grep(($_!=undef),split(/ /,substr $line,42));
    $coords[$stat]=@coords;
}

print $coords['10160354001'];

close(COORDS);
```

Comment: You must be running out of physical memory, causing the OS to use the disk as RAM (virtual memory), causing performance to plummet.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. This will find multiple bugs in the code you posted.

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM(of which 11.8GB was free at the scripts launch) and the file is only about 1.3MB.

Comment: Still, don't use 'foreach' to read a file. Use 'while'.

Comment: Put `print(time, "\n");` at the start of the loop and give the first 10 results.

Comment: (Oops, there was a typo in code in previous comment. Fixed)

Comment: 0
24
36
39
42
45
48
51
53
56
59
62

Comment: That is formatted as seconds since launch.

Comment: Can you monitor memory usage (ps -l) as the script runs? You are using a lot of it, and not because of the 'foreach', though that should be changed anyway.

Comment: I used top since I know it better.

Comment: About 13GB in use by the process. How?

Comment: Heard of 'sparse arrays'? Perl's arrays are not memory optimized to be sparse. Instead, a hash might be appropriate.

Comment: Isn't that using a Hash? `%coords = {}`?

Comment: @MrDgall Yes, that's a hash, but you're not actually using it (you're referring to an `@coords` in all other places). Just `use strict; use warnings` which will point out the problem: “*Global symbol `@coords` requires explicit package name*”. Hash entries are accessed with `{…}` not with `[…]`.

Comment: Thanks @amon. I made the changes (changed the names of all the variables to prevent type collision) to the rest after -ikegami pointed out to use the strict and warnings pragmas. It was indeed the false [$stat] that was causing it. Stupid mistake to make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$coords['10160354001'] = ...` is an assignment to an array element, and a large one at that. This statement will cause Perl to allocate an array with room for at least 10160354002 elements.

You meant to use a hash:

```
$coords{$stat} = "@coords";
...
print $coords{'10160354001'};
```

`use strict` and `use warnings` would have alerted you to this and other problems with your code.

Comment: I guess I was wrong. `use strict; use warnings;` would have found the relevant problem!